# GoogleSheets: How to disable functions in a function

Tags: function, google-apps-script, google-sheets

If I click on "TopLeft" button how can I write a script that will disables "BottomLeft" from being clicked on(disabling the script that is written.)

[image]

Comment: removed excel tag as is not relevant, add tags for gas and google spreadsheet

Comment: Just disable the button with CSS.

Answer (score 1):

From what I see in your screen capture these 'buttons' (which are actually drawings to which you can assign a function manually from the Google Spreadsheet interface) are just shortcuts to spreadsheet script functions.

You can't do anything to it using script, you can't disable nor modify them in any way.

You could use some permanent data (using Properties service for example) to simulate the behavior you are trying to get (prevent execution of one function if another one was executed) but it would rapidly become quite cumbersome...

You should consider using a HTML interface with "real" buttons that can also call script functions and that you can manage the way you want. Such a HTML interface could be located in the sidebar, with the advantage that it won't "move" when you scroll into your sheet.